# Populate select option with JSON file

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions, json

I am having a problem with populating a select dropdown from a `JSON` file.
I am modifying an existing [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/age-verify/), and I want to include countries that we want to see to.

#### The `JSON` FILE

```
{
 "AX": {
    "name": "&Aring;land Islands",
    "lpa": "18",
    "affirm_non_muslim": false
 },
 "AF": {
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "lpa": "0",
    "affirm_non_muslim": false
 },
 "AL": {
    "name": "Albania",
    "lpa": "18",
    "affirm_non_muslim": false
 },
 "DZ": {
    "name": "Algeria",
    "lpa": "18",
    "affirm_non_muslim": false
 }
}
```

#### MY FUNCTION FILE

```
function av_get_json_data(){

    $json_url = require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../includes/data/country_age.json' );
    $args   = array('timeout' => 120);
    $json_feed = wp_remote_get( $json_url, $args );

    $json_string_in_array = array('$json_feed');
    $json_array = json_decode($json_string_in_array[0]);

    //$actual_feed  = json_decode($json_array);
    return $json_array;
}
```

#### Here is the output form

```
$form .= '</select> <select name="av_verify_l" id="av_verify_l">';

        foreach (av_get_json_data() as $data) :
            $form .= '<option value="" >' . $data . '</option>';
        endforeach;
        $form .='<select>';
```

#### FRONT-END OUTPUT

[image: Screenshot from 2017-01-20 19:21:17.png]

#### QUESTION

How can I output the JSON file countries in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Edit output form with
`$form .= '<option value="" >' . $data['name'] . '</option>';`